# Can't read bytes message via JMX in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: java, jmx, activemq-artemis

I am reading a message via JMX. If it is text then everything is OK, but if it is byte then it gives such an error. I can't figure out how I should read a byte message and get its text in a string.

Here's my Java code:

```java
public static JMXMessage showMessage(QueueControl queueControl) {
    JMXHeaders jmxHeaders;
    JMXMessage jmxMessage;
    String body;
    String replyTo = null;
    String correlationId = null;
    try {
        CompositeData[] messages = queueControl.browse();
        j = queueLength - i;
        if (j > queueLength - 1) {
            i = 1;
            j = queueLength - i;
        }
        if (j < 0) {
            i = queueLength;
            j = 0;
        }

        TabularData stringProps = (TabularData) messages[j].get(CompositeDataConstants.STRING_PROPERTIES);
        for (CompositeData o : (Collection<CompositeData>) stringProps.values()) {
            Object key = o.get("key");
            if (key.equals("JMSReplyTo")) {
                replyTo = o.get("value").toString();
            }
            if (key.equals("JMSCorrelationID")) {
                correlationId = o.get("value").toString();
            }
        }
        jmxHeaders = new JMXHeaders(messages[j].get(CompositeDataConstants.TYPE).toString(),
                messages[j].get(CompositeDataConstants.EXPIRATION).toString(),
                messages[j].get(CompositeDataConstants.DURABLE).toString(),
                replyTo,
                messages[j].get(CompositeDataConstants.MESSAGE_ID).toString(),
                messages[j].get(CompositeDataConstants.TIMESTAMP).toString(),
                correlationId,
                messages[j].get(CompositeDataConstants.PRIORITY).toString());
        body = (String) messages[j].get(CompositeDataConstants.TEXT_BODY);
        jmxMessage = new JMXMessage(jmxHeaders, body);

        return jmxMessage;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Error code:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.management.openmbean.InvalidKeyException: Argument key="text" is not an existing item name for this CompositeData instance.
    at jmxClientUIPConsole.BuildGet.showMessage(BuildGet.java:155)
    at jmxClientUIPConsole.DConsoleFrameControllerGetMessage.viewMessage(DConsoleFrameControllerGetMessage.java:166)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: javax.management.openmbean.InvalidKeyException: Argument key="text" is not an existing item name for this CompositeData instance.
    at java.management/javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport.get(CompositeDataSupport.java:270)
    at jmxClientUIPConsole.BuildGet.showMessage(BuildGet.java:150)
    ... 63 more
```

That is the error in this line:

```java
body = (String) messages[j].get(CompositeDataConstants.TEXT_BODY);
```

How can I then determine in this method what message came to me (byte or text)? And how do I get the message in bytes from the queue?

Comment: I mean reading from the queue. And how can I then determine in this method what message came to me (byte or text)? And how do I get the message in bytes from the queue?

Comment: Do you have any feedback on any of the other questions you've asked recently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bodies of a JMS `BytesMessage` and `TextMessage` are serialized differently because the former is a `byte[]` and the latter is a `String`. You are attempting to get the *text* body out of a `BytesMessage` which doesn't exist and therefore you receive the `InvalidKeyException`.

However, you can detect the kind of message it is and then adjust accordingly, e.g.:

```java
      QueueControl queueControl = ...
      CompositeData[] messages = queueControl.browse();
      for (CompositeData message : messages) {
         if ((byte) message.get(CompositeDataConstants.TYPE) == (byte) 4) {
            System.out.println("This is a BytesMessage");
         } else {
            System.out.println("This is a TextMessage");
         }
      }
```

If you want to get the `byte[]` body of the message you can do so like this:

```
byte[] body = (byte[]) message.get(CompositeDataConstants.BODY);
```

Of course, in order to actually *decode* they `byte[]` into a `String` for example you'll need to know how it was encoded in the first place. `String` objects in Java can be encoded many different ways although the most common is probably using UTF-8 in which case the code would look something like:

```java
String body = Strings.getString((byte[]) message.get(CompositeDataConstants.BODY), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```